# Crystal Report like Facility in Flutter PDF printing

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, report

Crystal Report provides facility like page header, details, page footer,
where details section of page expands automatically in case of multi page.

In flutter PDF is it possible to design report same as crystal report where
detail section automatically expands to end of page in case of multipage.

Comment: Could you find a workaround for this? Can you please share your experience!

Comment: I also want to know the same